# Is there a way to implement an adapter or interface without changing a class that uses it in this situation?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, adapter

I'm trying to learn and understand interfaces, adapters, and dependency injection and how they can be used to achieve abstraction.

**TLDR:** How to change the way function\class uses the interface without changing said class\function's code?

I would also like it if you could point out errors in my thinking.

**The Example:**
Let's say I need to develop a logging mechanism (implement an ILogger interface) for some class (MoneyAdder) that I'm not allowed to modify. I also need to **implement usage** *(please give me a correct term for this)* of some other loggers via an adapter so we could choose the best way.

```
class MoneyAdder
{
    private ILogger logger;
    private Customer customer;
    public MoneyAdder(ILogger logger, Customer customer)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    public void AddMoney(int amount)
    {
        logger.log("Doing work!");
        customer.balance+=amount;
        logger.log("I'm done!");
    }
}
```

1. This is what I did at first:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void log(string str);
}

public class MyLogger : ILogger
{
    public void log(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"LOG - {str}");
    }
}
```

In this case, I have complete control over the interface definition, the class that implements it, and is able to use the log string that is given any way I want.

2. We know that *OtherLogger* requires a string and it's length to write a log. To use it I wrote an adapter like this:

```
public class OtherLogger
{
    //We know it needs a string and its length for some reason.
    public void log2(string str, int i);
}

public class OtherLoggerAdapter : ILogger
{
    private OtherLogger ol = new OtherLogger();
    public void log(string str)
    {
        ol.log2(str, str.Length);
    }
}
```

This way I **adapt** the other dll to my interface. When the adapter is called I, in turn, call the different method name. I'm also able to provide an *int* it needs because it's computable from the input.

3. Now I need to add another logger that needs a log string and an assembly from which it was referenced. I'm able to provide it as well. It is not computable from the log string, but I'm able to give it any *common* information, like the environment variables or the program name because it is *common* for the program, MoneyAdder class, and StrangeLoggerAdapter.

```
public class StrangeLogger
{
    public void logS(string str, System.Reflection.Assembly assembly);
}

public class StrangeLoggerAdapter : ILogger
{
    private StrangeLogger sl = new StrangeLogger();

    public void log(string str)
    {
        sl.logS(str, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

4. The final logger is an old mechanism that was used before. It was directly referenced and called inside MoneyAdder's other methods. *(Tightly coupled, is this the correct term?)*. The logging method definition is as follows:

```
public class OldLogger
{
    public void log(string str, string customerName);
}
```

It needs a customer name, but it is neither computable from the log string, nor it can be accessed from any adapter I can write. The only way to use it is to "inject" a customer name into a logger like this:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void log(string str);
    void injectCustomer(string customerName);
}
```

And then to implement it in an adapter like this:

```
public class OldLoggerAdapter
{
    private string customerName;
    private OldLogger ol = new OldLogger();
    public void injectCustomer(string customerName)
    {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public void log(string str)
    {
        ol.log(str, this.customerName);
    }
}
```

However, to use the implementation I still need to modify (which I'm not allowed to do) either the MoneyAdder class or AddMoney method to use the injection function.

```
class MoneyAdder
{
    private ILogger logger;
    private Customer customer;
    public MoneyAdder(ILogger logger, Customer customer)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.logger.injectCustomer(customer.Name);
    }
    public void AddMoney(int amount)
    {
        logger.log("Doing work!");
        customer.balance+=amount;
        logger.log("I'm done!");
    }
}
```

**The question:**
To implement a logging function I can only use the information, that is either provided to the function via a method or can be computed from that information, or is global to the entire program.

There is no way to directly provide or inject information **without modifying the calling function.**

**Or is there?**

Is there a way, using some System\Reflexion\DI\IOC magic, to write something like:

*Hey, MoneyAdder, It's an OldLogger that is currently used as ILogger. Whenever you call log(string str) you should actually call my method log(string str, string customerName). I know for sure you have a private property Customer that has a Customer.Name, use that in my log method as a "customerName"*.

Comment: If your `MoneyAdder` class requires an old logger, then it should take something like an `IOldLogger` interface. Your concrete implementation of your logger might still implement both interfaces of course.

Comment: You don't need to modify `MoneyAdder`. The consumer needs to be responsible for calling `injectCustomer` (on the full `OldLoggerAdapter` reference because `ILogger` shouldn't be modified to include that method) before passing the `ILogger` reference to the `MoneyAdder` constructor.